# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'UnitOfWork' while attempting to activate 'Controller'

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an annoying error trying to implement unitofwork with netcore 3.0

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DataAccess.EF.UnitOfWork' while attempting to activate 'ShopAPI.Controllers.CategoryController'.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContext")));

    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    );
    services.AddControllers();

    var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        mc.AddProfile(new AutoMapperConfigurationProfile());
    });

    IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);
}
```

UnitOfWork

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

public ICategoryRepository CategoryRepositoryAsync => new CategoryRepository(_context);
public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

CategoryRepository

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

public CategoryRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) 
    :base(context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

ApplicationDbContext

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) 
    : base(options)
{
}
```

Controller

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

public CategoryController(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

I kept the code samples on the DI, because I feel like there is a problem, or I missed something entirely.
I just started with .NET Core and I am not sure what's wrong with this.
I google before this and got some white hair too.

Comment: You have registered `IUnitOfWork` so your controller should be: `public CategoryController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)`, exactly the same as the linked duplicate.

Comment: You are right, I was reading that post from top to bottom and I checked the constructor. Yep it is "IUnitOfWork" but it wasn't I guess I am tired and already not calm enough. Thank you! Should I delete this?

Comment: Leave it here if you like, it's not causing a problem.